# How can I parse JSON in GoLang if nested content uses dynamic keys?

Tags: json, parsing, go

I received JSON below from a client API but i am struggling to get nested JSON content. How can I parse it if the inner keys are dynamic?

```
const jsonStream = `
{
    "items": {
        "bvu62fu6dq": {
            "name": "john",
            "age": 23,
            "xyz": "weu33s"
        },
        "iaxdw23fq": {
            "name": "kelly",
            "age": 21,
            "xyz": "weu33s"
        }
    }
}`
```

This is what i have tried below by looping the map to extract the value of name and age from above JSON string; but it returns map with nil value as a result.
[goplaygound](http://play.golang.org/p/Y5-2cwsRhE)

```
type Person struct {
    Name string `json:"name"`
    Age  int    `json:"age"`
}
type Item struct {
    Contact struct {
        Info map[string]Person
    } `json:"items"`
}

func main() {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(strings.NewReader(jsonStream))
    for {
        var item Item
        if err := dec.Decode(&item); err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", item.Contact.Info["bvu62fu6dq"].Name)
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you edit your question explaining the point of the unique keys? It is only mentioned in the title

Comment: It will be easier if you say that, and in what form you need to get.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this instead, looks like you just have your structure set up incorrectly:

http://play.golang.org/p/VRKbv-GVQB

You need to parse the entire json string, which is an object that contains a single element named `items`. `items` then contains a map of `string` -> `Person` objects.

If you only want to extract `name` and `age` from each person, you do it by grabbing `data.Items["bvu62fu6dq"].Name`.

If you want dynamic keys inside the `Person`, you'll need to do `map[string]interface{}` instead of `Person` in order to capture the dynamic keys again. It would look something like:

```
type Data struct {
    Items map[string]map[string]interface{} `json:"items"`
}
...
fmt.Printf("%v\n", data.Items["bvu62fu6dq"]["name"]
fmt.Printf("%v\n", data.Items["bvu62fu6dq"]["age"]
fmt.Printf("%v\n", data.Items["bvu62fu6dq"]["xyz"]
```