# Parse JSON having sibling dynamic keys alongside with static in Go

Tags: json, go, dynamic, unmarshalling

I need to parse this json

```
{
    "version": "1.1.29-snapshot",
    "linux-amd64": {
        "url": "https://origin/path",
        "size": 7794688,
        "sha256": "14b3c3ad05e3a98d30ee7e774646aec7ffa8825a1f6f4d9c01e08bf2d8a08646"
    },
    "windows-amd64": {
        "url": "https://origin/path",
        "size": 8102400,
        "sha256": "01b8b927388f774bdda4b5394e381beb592d8ef0ceed69324d1d42f6605ab56d"
    }
}
```

Keys like `linux-amd64` are dynamic and theirs amount is arbitrary. I tried something like that to describe it and unmarshal. Obviously it doesn't work. `Items` is always empty.

```
type FileInfo struct {
    Url    string `json:"url"`
    Size   int64  `json:"size"`
    Sha256 string `json:"sha256"`
}

type UpdateInfo struct {
    Version string `json:"version"`
    Items   map[string]FileInfo
}
```

It's similar to this [use case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32805461/how-can-i-parse-json-in-golang-if-nested-content-uses-dynamic-keys), but has no parent key `items`. I suppose I can use 3rd party library or `map[string]interface{}` approach, but I'm interested in knowing how to achieve this with explicitly declared types.

The rest of the parsing code is:

```
func parseUpdateJson(jsonStr []byte) (UpdateInfo, error) {
    var allInfo = UpdateInfo{Items: make(map[string]FileInfo)}
    var err = json.Unmarshal(jsonStr, &allInfo)
    return allInfo, err
}
```

Look at the link I attached and you will realize that is not that simple as you think. Also I pointed that I interested in typed approach. Ok, how to declare this `map[string]FileInfo` to get parsed?

Comment: If the keys are dynamic, then you can only use a map. If you want to change the structure while you are decoding the json, there are lots of examples of doing that with a [json.Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler), but that still must use a map internally.

Comment: It's obvious due to there is no `Items` field in source json...

Comment: @JimB The version is static and the rest is dynamic

Comment: I've created a video that talks about how to do hybrid struct/maps in Go.  I may be able to turn this into an answer later on, but don't have time at this exact moment.  [Watch here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsN11YAEJHY&t=1455s)

Comment: It doesn't matter if one of N dynamic keys is static, you still need to use a map. There is nothing in `Items`, because there is no `"items"` in the JSON.

Comment: @JimB I know that I can use `map[string]interface{}` on top level, but I want to know is there another "typed" way of doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can create a `json.Unmarshaller` to decode the json into a map, then apply those values to your struct: https://play.golang.org/p/j1JXMpc4Q9u

```
type FileInfo struct {
    Url    string `json:"url"`
    Size   int64  `json:"size"`
    Sha256 string `json:"sha256"`
}

type UpdateInfo struct {
    Version string `json:"version"`
    Items   map[string]FileInfo
}

func (i *UpdateInfo) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    tmp := map[string]json.RawMessage{}
    err := json.Unmarshal(d, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(tmp["version"], &i.Version)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    delete(tmp, "version")

    i.Items = map[string]FileInfo{}

    for k, v := range tmp {
        var item FileInfo
        err := json.Unmarshal(v, &item)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }

        i.Items[k] = item
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This answer is adapted from [this recipe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vsN11YAEJHY&t=1455s) in my YouTube video on advanced JSON handling in Go.

```golang
func (u *UpdateInfo) UnmarshalJSON(d []byte) error {
    var x struct {
        UpdateInfo
        UnmarshalJSON struct{}
    }
    if err := json.Unmarshal(d, &x); err != nil {
        return err
    }
    var y map[string]json.RawMessage{}
    if err := json.Unsmarshal(d, &y); err != nil {
        return err
    }


    delete(y, "version"_ // We don't need this in the map
    *u = x.UpdateInfo
    u.Items = make(map[string]FileInfo, len(y))
    for k, v := range y {
        var info FileInfo
        if err := json.Unmarshal(v, &info); err != nil {
            return err
        }
        u.Items[k] = info
    }
    return nil
}
```

It:

1. Unmarshals the JSON into the struct directly, to get the struct fields.
2. It re-unmarshals into a map of `map[string]json.RawMessage` to get the arbitrary keys. This is necessary since the value of `version` is not of type `FileInfo`, and trying to unmarshal directly into `map[string]FileInfo` will thus error.
3. It deletes the keys we know we already got in the struct fields.
4. It then iterates through the map of `string` to `json.RawMessage`, and finally unmarshals each value into the `FileInfo` type, and stores it in the final object.

---

If you really don't want to unmarshal multiple times, your next best option is to iterate over the JSON tokens in your input by using the [`json.Decoder`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Decoder) type. I've done this in a couple of performance-sensitive bits of code, but it makes your code INCREDIBLY hard to read, and in almost all cases is not worth the effort.

Comment: So there is no way to do it at once avoiding extra code of deleting static keys, isn't there?

Comment: Sure, there's a way. It's much much more complicated, as it basically means writing a custom JSON unmarshaler. Unless this code is incredibly performance sensitive, there's probably no reason to do that, though.

Comment: @Filmzy Well the 3rd party library is the way. That is the answer I looked for...

Comment: @4xy: I'm sorry, what 3rd party library?

Comment: Something that is out of standard library if there is standard. In other words something that is not included in the box.

Comment: In that sense, yes, it's not included in the stdlib. I'm not aware of any 3rd party library that does it, either, though. As far as I know, you must do it yourself.